# How to align a single legend over two seaborn barplots?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, legend, subplot

I would like to have a single legend that nicely fits on top of both the subplots (doesn't necessarily need to span the entire width of the plots, but needs to be outside the plot). I know you can work with `bbox_to_anchor()` but somehow this doesn't seem to work nicely. It always moves one subplot away.

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, ax = ax[0])
ax[0].legend_.remove()
sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, ax = ax[1])
sns.move_legend(ax[1], loc = "center", bbox_to_anchor=(-0.5, 1.1), ncol=2, title=None, frameon=False)
fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Is the issue the gaps that moving the legends creates? Or the fact that you need to use `bbox_to_anchor`?

Comment: @Alex The issue is the gap. I want it to be tidy.

Comment: You need `move_legend` after `plt.tight_layout()`.   `tight_layout` assumes the legend only belongs to the second subplot.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that I would approach closing the gap.

### 1: Use a `sns.catplot`:

This potentially requires doubling your data, though if you're plotting different variables in each subplot you may be able to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) your data

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Load the dataset twice
tips_a = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips_b = sns.load_dataset("tips")
# Add a dummy facet variable
tips_a["col"] = "A"
tips_b["col"] = "B"

# Concat them
tips = pd.concat([tips_a, tips_b])

# Use the dummy variable for the `col` param
g = sns.catplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, kind="bar", col="col")
# Remove the titles and move the legend
g.set_titles("")
sns.move_legend(g, loc="upper center", ncol=2, title=None, frameon=False)
```

[image]

---

### 2: `autoscale` the axes

This still requires a little bit of `bbox_to_anchor` fiddling and you probably want to change the right y-axis label (and ticks/ticklabels).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(7, 4))
sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].legend_.remove()
sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, ax=ax[1])
sns.move_legend(
    ax[1],
    loc="upper center",
    bbox_to_anchor=(-0.1, 1.1),
    ncol=2,
    title=None,
    frameon=False,
)

ax[0].autoscale()
ax[1].autoscale()
```

[image]